# select multiple rows from mysql but show one result from each id

Tags: php, mysql

i have mysql table like this

```
id   id_p   name    date
1     1     test1    2015-01-01
2     1     test1    2015-02-02
3     2     test2    2015-03-01
4     2     test2    2014-03-05
```

celect by date

```
select name, date from table1 where date <= (now() - interval 6 month)
```

and result is

```
name   date
test1  2015-01-01
test1  2015-02-02
test2  2015-02-02
test2  2014-03-05
```

how to get this result  how to limit

```
name   date
test1  2015-01-01
test2  2015-02-02
```

thank you for your help

Comment: try `group by name` at the end of the query

Comment: You mean `test2  2015-02-02` or maybe `test2  2015-03-01` (according to your table example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `GROUP BY`, which then means that your fields need to be properly set up otherwise mysql doesn't know which value to return.  In this case, I'm wrapping your `date` field in the `MIN` function since it appears you wanted the lowest / earliest date.

So, in your case, modify the query like so:

```
SELECT `name`, MIN(`date`) as `date`
    FROM table1 
    WHERE `date` <= (now() - interval 6 month)
    GROUP BY `name`
```